# Downloading File in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Completely new on .Net core from MVC5, so how does download file works with .NET Core? I have tried writing down code but it has errors. Thanks in advance to the helpers.

Controller

```
public ActionResult Download()
    {
        string[] files = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "uploads");
        for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
        {
            files[i] = Path.GetFileName(files[i]);
        }
        ViewBag.Files = files;
        return View();
    }

    public FileResult DownloadFile(string fileName)
    {
        var filepath = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "uploads");
        return File(filepath, LineMapping.GetMimeMapping(filepath), fileName);
    }
```

View

```
  <h2>Downloads</h2>
 <table>
 <tr>
    <th>File Name</th>
    <th>Link</th>
 </tr>
 @for (var i =0; i <= Model.Count -1; i++) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Model[i].ToString()
        </td>
        <td>     
            @Html.ActionLink("Download", "Download", new  { ImageName=@Model[i].ToString() })           
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Please read the tag description http://stackoverflow.com/tags/asp.net-mvc6/info, before adding a tag. The info section says why you shouldn't use mvc6 tags

Comment: Exactly what errors are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

The code as written will not even compile because `Path.Combine` does not return a list of files.  You will also get parsing errors in your view because you reference `Model` but you don't have a model.  Also, your parameter `ImageName` doesn't match your action's parameter name.  Several other issues with the code too (using `Count` on an array - use `Count()` or `Length`.

I think you are trying to do something like this?

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Download()
{
   string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "uploads"));
   for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
   {
      files[i] = Path.GetFileName(files[i]);
   }

   return View(files);
}

public FileResult DownloadFile(string fileName)
{
   var filepath = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "uploads", fileName);
   return File(filepath, "application/pdf", fileName);
}
```

**View**

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>File Name</th>
      <th>Link</th>
   </tr>
   @for (var i = 0; i <= Model.Length - 1; i++)
   {
      <tr>
         <td>
            @Model[i].ToString()
         </td>
         <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Download", "DownloadFile", new { fileName = @Model[i].ToString() })
         </td>
      </tr>
   }
</table>
```

Comment: Compilation Error:- LineMapping does not contain a defination for GetMimeMapping

Comment: That was your code I copied in.  Not sure what you are trying to do there.  What is LineMapping?  If I put in `"UTF-8"` it works fine

Comment: I saw from an online resource and added linemapping, I have no absolute idea what it actually does.

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't UTF-8, it was `text/plain` that I used.  What type of files are these?  Use the appropriate MIME type there instead of your call to `linemapping`

Comment: I have to download the uploaded .pdf files and I am kind of lost implementing that logic with .net core.

Comment: use `application/pdf` there then.  See the updated code in my answer.